# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'height') at script.js:3:19

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to change css height and width properties of a class of img tags using javascript. But it isn't showing any effect rather sending an error mentioned in the title. I've included the script src file just before closing body tag and also have img elements by class name of 'card-img-top'. I'm attaching the code here as well.

`

```
let cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card-img-top');

cards.style.height='20px';
cards.style.width='20px';
```

`

I also tried shifting the position of script tag in case could see any change, but it didn't change.
Also to mention that I'm using bootstrap cards and I'm trying to change the height and width of images in those cards.

Thank You.

Comment: `cards[0].style.height='20px';` will do that.

Answer (score 0):

cards is an array. You can't set the property of entire array. You will have to set property individually. So you can simply iterate through the entire array.

```
    for(card of cards){
        cards.style.height='20px';
        cards.style.width='20px';
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can JQUERY for that. it's very usefull in manipulate to DOM. use given code below:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.2.min.js" integrity="sha256-2krYZKh//PcchRtd+H+VyyQoZ/e3EcrkxhM8ycwASPA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script> $('.cards').css({"width":"20px","height":"20px"}); </script>
```